# Renv issues with tidyverse install

Tags: r, tidyverse, renv

I am working in an R project with renv initialised. I have the latest version of renv and R. renv cannot see tidyverse in the project library (renv::status() says it is missing though the folder is in my renv library folder), but I also cannot get tidyverse installed in the project library using various methods. If I run renv::install("tidyverse") the error says "package "tidyverse is not available". If I run utils::install.packages("tidyverse") the error is:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Session info:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4        R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.0  magrittr_2.0.3    glue_1.7.0       
 [6] tibble_3.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   dplyr_1.1.4       generics_0.1.3    lifecycle_1.0.4  
[11] cli_3.6.2         fansi_1.0.6       vctrs_0.6.5       renv_1.0.3        compiler_4.3.2   
[16] rstudioapi_0.15.0 tools_4.3.2       pillar_1.9.0      rlang_1.1.3
```

renv::diagnostics() output:

```
Diagnostics Report [renv 1.0.3]
===============================

# Session Info ---------------------------------------------------------------
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

time zone: Europe/London
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4        R6_2.5.1          tidyselect_1.2.0  magrittr_2.0.3   
 [5] glue_1.7.0        tibble_3.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   dplyr_1.1.4      
 [9] generics_0.1.3    lifecycle_1.0.4   cli_3.6.2         fansi_1.0.6      
[13] vctrs_0.6.5       renv_1.0.3        compiler_4.3.2    rstudioapi_0.15.0
[17] tools_4.3.2       pillar_1.9.0      rlang_1.1.3      

# Project --------------------------------------------------------------------
Project path: "~/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis"

# Status ---------------------------------------------------------------------
The following package(s) are missing their DESCRIPTION files:
- jquerylib [C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/jquerylib]
These may be left over from a prior, failed installation attempt.
Consider removing or reinstalling these packages.

The following package(s) are missing:

 package   installed recorded used
 tidyverse n         n        y   

See ?renv::status() for advice on resolving these issues.

# Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
The following package(s) are missing their DESCRIPTION files:
- jquerylib [C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/jquerylib]
These may be left over from a prior, failed installation attempt.
Consider removing or reinstalling these packages.

                Library Source Lockfile Source Path Dependency
DBI               1.2.1   RSPM    1.2.1   RSPM  [1]   indirect
KernSmooth      2.23-22   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
MASS             7.3-60   CRAN   7.3-60   CRAN  [1]   indirect
Matrix          1.6-1.1   CRAN  1.6-1.1   CRAN  [1]   indirect
NDRSAfunctions    0.2.0 GitHub    0.2.0 GitHub  [1]     direct
R6                2.5.1   RSPM    2.5.1   RSPM  [1]   indirect
RColorBrewer      1.1-3   RSPM    1.1-3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
RJDBC            0.2-10   CRAN   0.2-10   CRAN  [1]   indirect
RPostgreSQL       0.7-6   CRAN    0.7-6   CRAN  [1]   indirect
Rcpp             1.0.12   CRAN   1.0.12   CRAN  [1]   indirect
askpass           1.2.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
backports         1.4.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
base64enc         0.1-3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
bit               4.0.5   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
bit64             4.0.5   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
blob              1.2.4   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
boot           1.3-28.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
broom             1.0.5   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
bslib             0.6.1   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
cachem            1.0.8   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
callr             3.7.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
cellranger        1.1.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
class            7.3-22   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
cli               3.6.2   RSPM    3.6.2   RSPM  [1]   indirect
clipr             0.8.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
cluster           2.1.4   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
codetools        0.2-19   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
colorspace        2.1-0   RSPM    2.1-0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
conflicted        1.2.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
cpp11             0.4.7   RSPM    0.4.7   RSPM  [1]   indirect
crayon            1.5.2   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
curl              5.2.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
data.table      1.14.10   RSPM  1.14.10   RSPM  [1]   indirect
dbplyr            2.4.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
digest           0.6.34   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
dplyr             1.1.4   RSPM    1.1.4   RSPM  [1]     direct
dtplyr            1.3.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
ellipsis          0.3.2   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
evaluate           0.23   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
fansi             1.0.6   RSPM    1.0.6   RSPM  [1]   indirect
farver            2.1.1   RSPM    2.1.1   RSPM  [1]   indirect
fastmap           1.1.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
fontawesome       0.5.2   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
forcats           1.0.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
foreign          0.8-85   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
fs                1.6.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
gargle            1.5.2   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
generics          0.1.3   RSPM    0.1.3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
getPass           0.2-4   CRAN    0.2-4   CRAN  [1]   indirect
ggplot2           3.4.4   RSPM    3.4.4   RSPM  [1]   indirect
glue              1.7.0   RSPM    1.7.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
googledrive       2.1.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
googlesheets4     1.1.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
grDevices          <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
graphics           <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
grid               <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
gtable            0.3.4   RSPM    0.3.4   RSPM  [1]   indirect
haven             2.5.4   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
highr              0.10   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
hms               1.1.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
htmltools         0.5.7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
httr              1.4.7   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
ids               1.0.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
isoband           0.2.7   RSPM    0.2.7   RSPM  [1]   indirect
jsonlite          1.8.8   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
knitr              1.45   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
labeling          0.4.3   RSPM    0.4.3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
lattice          0.21-9   CRAN   0.21-9   CRAN  [1]   indirect
lifecycle         1.0.4   RSPM    1.0.4   RSPM  [1]   indirect
lubridate         1.9.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
magrittr          2.0.3   RSPM    2.0.3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
memoise           2.0.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
methods            <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
mgcv              1.9-0   CRAN    1.9-0   CRAN  [1]   indirect
mime               0.12   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
modelr           0.1.11   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
munsell           0.5.0   RSPM    0.5.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
nlme            3.1-163   CRAN  3.1-163   CRAN  [1]   indirect
nnet             7.3-19   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
openssl           2.1.1   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
pillar            1.9.0   RSPM    1.9.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
pkgconfig         2.0.3   RSPM    2.0.3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
plyr              1.8.9   CRAN    1.8.9   CRAN  [1]     direct
prettyunits       1.2.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
processx          3.8.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
progress          1.2.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
ps                1.7.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
purrr             1.0.2   RSPM    1.0.2   RSPM  [1]   indirect
rJava            1.0-10   CRAN   1.0-10   CRAN  [1]   indirect
ragg              1.2.7   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
rappdirs          0.3.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
readr             2.1.5   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
readxl            1.4.3   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
rematch           2.0.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
rematch2          2.1.2   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
renv              1.0.3   CRAN    1.0.3   CRAN  [1]     direct
reprex            2.1.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
rlang             1.1.3   RSPM    1.1.3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
rmarkdown          2.25   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
rpart            4.1.21   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
rstudioapi       0.15.0   CRAN   0.15.0   CRAN  [1]   indirect
sass              0.4.8   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
scales            1.3.0   RSPM    1.3.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
spatial          7.3-17   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
splines            <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
stats              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
stringi           1.8.3   RSPM    1.8.3   RSPM  [1]   indirect
stringr           1.5.1   RSPM    1.5.1   RSPM  [1]   indirect
survival          3.5-7   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [2]       <NA>
svDialogs         1.1.0   CRAN    1.1.0   CRAN  [1]   indirect
svGUI             1.0.1   CRAN    1.0.1   CRAN  [1]   indirect
sys               3.4.2   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
systemfonts       1.0.5   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
textshaping       0.3.7   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
tibble            3.2.1   RSPM    3.2.1   RSPM  [1]   indirect
tidyr             1.3.0   RSPM    1.3.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
tidyselect        1.2.0   RSPM    1.2.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
tidyverse          <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA> <NA>     direct
timechange        0.3.0   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
tinytex            0.49   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
tools              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
tzdb              0.4.0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
utf8              1.2.4   RSPM    1.2.4   RSPM  [1]   indirect
utils              <NA>   <NA>     <NA>   <NA>  [2]   indirect
uuid              1.2-0   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
vctrs             0.6.5   RSPM    0.6.5   RSPM  [1]   indirect
viridisLite       0.4.2   RSPM    0.4.2   RSPM  [1]   indirect
vroom             1.6.5   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
withr             3.0.0   RSPM    3.0.0   RSPM  [1]   indirect
xfun               0.41   RSPM     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
xlsx              0.6.5   CRAN    0.6.5   CRAN  [1]     direct
xlsxjars          0.6.1   CRAN    0.6.1   CRAN  [1]   indirect
xml2              1.3.6   CRAN     <NA>   <NA>  [1]       <NA>
yaml              2.3.8   RSPM    2.3.8   RSPM  [1]   indirect

[1]: C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32
[2]: C:/Users/elau2/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/sandbox/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1e360f03                                                           

# ABI ------------------------------------------------------------------------
- ABI conflict checks are not yet implemented on Windows.

# User Profile ---------------------------------------------------------------
[1] Source  Package Require Version Dev    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

# Settings -------------------------------------------------------------------
List of 13
 $ bioconductor.version     : NULL
 $ external.libraries       : chr(0) 
 $ ignored.packages         : chr(0) 
 $ package.dependency.fields: chr [1:3] "Imports" "Depends" "LinkingTo"
 $ ppm.enabled              : NULL
 $ ppm.ignored.urls         : chr(0) 
 $ r.version                : NULL
 $ snapshot.type            : chr "implicit"
 $ use.cache                : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.cellar        : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.library       : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.ignore.local         : logi TRUE
 $ vcs.manage.ignores       : logi TRUE

# Options --------------------------------------------------------------------
List of 8
 $ defaultPackages                     : chr [1:6] "datasets" "utils" "grDevices" "graphics" ...
 $ download.file.method                : NULL
 $ download.file.extra                 : NULL
 $ install.packages.compile.from.source: chr "interactive"
 $ pkgType                             : chr "both"
 $ repos                               : Named chr "https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "CRAN"
 $ renv.consent                        : logi TRUE
 $ renv.verbose                        : logi TRUE

# Environment Variables ------------------------------------------------------
HOME                        = C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents
LANG                        = <NA>
MAKE                        = <NA>
R_LIBS                      = <NA>
R_LIBS_SITE                 = C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/site-library
R_LIBS_USER                 = C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis/renv/library/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32
RENV_DEFAULT_R_ENVIRON      = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_ENVIRON_USER = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS         = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS_SITE    = C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-43~1.2/site-library
RENV_DEFAULT_R_LIBS_USER    = C:\Users\elau2\AppData\Local/R/win-library/4.3
RENV_DEFAULT_R_PROFILE      = <NA>
RENV_DEFAULT_R_PROFILE_USER = <NA>
RENV_DOWNLOAD_FILE_METHOD   = libcurl
RENV_PROJECT                = C:/Users/elau2/OneDrive - NHS Digital/Documents/Linked CPES-registry analysis C drive/Linked_CPES_analysis

# PATH -----------------------------------------------------------------------
- C:\rtools43\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin
- C:\rtools43\usr\bin
- C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\x64
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
- C:\Windows\system32
- C:\Windows
- C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
- C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
- C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts
- C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
- C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
- C:\WINDOWS\system32
- C:\WINDOWS
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
- C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
- C:\Program Files\dotnet\
- C:\Users\elau2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
- C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\bin\quarto\bin
- C:\Program Files\RStudio\resources\app\bin\postback

# Cache ----------------------------------------------------------------------
There are a total of 192 packages installed in the renv cache.
Cache path: "C:/Users/elau2/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/cache/v5/R-4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

I have tried:

- changing the CRAN repo (currently on Global (CDN) but also tried others)
- unticked "use secure download method for HTTP"
- changing CRAN repo in my activate.R file in the renv folder
- updating renv and using dev version

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like your computer can't access the URL https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/latest/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES. Can you get to that page from a browser? Are you using a proxy server or a firewall or anything that might be blocking access for R?